# Showing summary of model on test data (R Shiny App)

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R Shiny. I have created a simple linear regression model and saved it using

```
save(regressor , file = 'SimpleLinearRegression.rda')
```

Now I have created a Shiny R app where a user can upload a file (test data), and I want my saved model to load and run on the test data. Then, I want to show the summary of the model.

I have this so far:

```
output$modelSummary <- renderPrint({
model <- load(file = "SimpleLinearRegression.rda",.GlobalEnv)  })
```

Now, how do I run this on my test data? i.e. the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following code:

```
output$modelSummary <- renderPrint({
req(input$file1)
df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
               header = input$header,
               sep = input$sep,
               quote = input$quote)
model <- load(file = "SimpleLinearRegression.rda")
YE <- data.frame(YearsExperience = df$YearsExperience)
dat2 <- data.frame(YE, Predicted = predict(get(model), YE))
print(merge(df, dat2, by = 'YearsExperience', all.y = TRUE)) })
```